# Are forwarded methods inlined by JIT in Java?

Tags: java

Does JIT inline methods in the form of

```
public void forwardCall(int argument) {
    MyStaticClass.forwardCallTarget(argument);
}
```

?

Let's assume that the forwarding class has no derived or base classes (the `forwardCall` method is quasy-final).

I see a lot of discussion online about getters/setters being inlined, but not much about method forwarding.

Comment: Use `-XX:+PrintInlining` and see!

Comment: There is nothing conceptually special about forwarding, so why should it deserve any extra mention? I think what you really want to know is if the JIT can inline across multiple call levels? (nested inlining)

Comment: Yeah, it's just code, from the JITC's point of view.  Pretty much all modern JITCs can inline multiple levels, so it's really just a question of whether the statistics make it appear profitable.

Answer (score 0):

Using PrintInlining as suggested, I can see that JIT can indeed inline multiple levels. I tested with 3 levels (regular method -> static method -> native method), Java 1.7.

Nice to know for sure :)